# How to return plain text in a zend controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to figure out how I can only return a simple text in a zend controller.

So far I've used this approach and it kinda works except when there's an exception occurs in the try block and it returns the exception error as well

```
try {
  //some exception happens
} catch() {

}
$this->getResponse()
  ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  ->setBody('test message')
  ->sendResponse();
exit;
```

And the output would be: test message + Exception trace

How can I get rid of the exception part?

Comment: Build up a variable of messages and put that into the response.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your question. Answer is deleted. Are you're sure you're catching the right exception? You should be able to _handle_ the exception without it spilling over into the response.

Comment: catch what? \Exception $e maybe? is it deliberately simplified?